# spring-data-mongodb Query.fields().slice() on @DBRef field throws MappingException

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I have a problem with sliced access to some @DBRef field in my model. I use spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.M1.jar

The model is like:

```
class Model {
....
@DBRef
List<OtherModel> members;
...
}
```

and I need sliced access to the members variable.

I use this query:

```
ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId("55c36f44f359d8a455a21f68");
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(objectId));
query.fields().slice("members", pageable.getOffset(), pageable.getPageSize());
List<Model> models = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Model.class);
```

But I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No id property found on class class [Ljava.lang.Integer;
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createDBRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:842)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.toDBRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.createDbRefFor(QueryMapper.java:460)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.convertAssociation(QueryMapper.java:417)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.convertAssociation(QueryMapper.java:378)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedKeyword(QueryMapper.java:257)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObjectForField(QueryMapper.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1647)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:563)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:558)
```

where a field

```
boolean needsAssociationConversion = property.isAssociation() && !keyword.isExists();
```

is set. It checks against isExists, but not against something like isSliced (which does not yet exist) and therefore is evaluated to true and, as a cause, tries to convert the non-existing association which is, in this case, just the slice-directive (an integer array). When I set the variable needsAssociationConversion to false while debugging, as if a kind of keyword.isSlice() check was done, everything works fine.

> **Is this a bug?**

**Executable project is here**

https://github.com/zhsyourai/sliceDemo

Comment: The exception talks about an Integer[] which doesn't seem to be part of the code you show. Where is this coming from?

Comment: @OliverGierke This come from `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper`. And this is the two param of `slice`

Comment: Well, I can certainly read the stacktrace. However, neither your model nor your query contain a reference to an Integer array. That makes obvious that some important parts are missing here. Please add the necessary information or provide a executable sample project. Also, please don't arbitrarily cross-post stuff, as that just steals everybody's time. Thanks.

Comment: @OliverGierke You are right. I am sorry,I will never cross-post. I will then add a project link. Thanks.

Comment: @OliverGierke This is a executable sample project [sliceDemo](https://github.com/zhsyourai/sliceDemo)

Comment: I ran `mvn clean test` and the build doesn't fail?

Comment: @OliverGierke  I do not write test, please ran `mvn clean spring-boot:run` and visit `http://localhost:8080/otherModelList`.

Comment: @OliverGierke Now, you can RUN `mvn clean test`, I write the test.